# AFnetworking duplicate symbol when linking

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, afnetworking

My project is using `AFNetworking 1.x`( include AFHttpClient, AFHTTPRequestOperation and so on) , and now I've to use a third party static library which using `AFNetworking 2`( remove the AFHttpClient) , and now I got many duplicate symbol error .

because my project has so many place using AFHttpClient& AFHTTPRequestOperation ，so I don't want to upgrade my `AFNetworking 1.x`, how can I solve this problem easily?(let my project and the static library use the diffrent AFNetworking properly)

Answer (score 0):

So you try to use duplicate files to one **Target**. You need remove duplicates from `Build Phases -> Compile Sources /or/ Link Binary With Libraries`.

If you want to use diff library you need create one more **Target** and link your new `AFNetrwoking` with this new **Target**.

Comment: you mean diffrent targets can make the same symbol exist at the same time？

Comment: Yeah. you can use identical classes wit diff settings like for a Dev or Prod

Comment: seems not working , I wrote a demo with two class each for a target , and it seems the classA in targetA can't find the symbol of classB in targetB in link time. i 've already set targetA's target dependency to targetB

Comment: No. For example. You have one class let's call it ClassA and ClassB with the same interface and className. Also you have 2 Targets let's call them Target1 and Target2. First ClassA link with Target1, second ClassB with Target2 both classes can use separately in different Targets

Comment: then ,if there's ClassC in targetA , ClassD in targetB (because it has somthing to do with ClassB) ,if ClassC wants to  reference ClassD , it seems not  possible,because C ,D is in diffrent target

Comment: Yes, you are right. In you problem you tired to use different version of AFNetwoking library and had the error with duplicates. I mean that you can use both of them only in different Targets

Comment: so it seems not possible to maintain two versions of the same library in a project -_-

Comment: It's possible in different targets. And you can use both of them in one class that will link with both targets.